# How to check if a filename with specific pattern exists in cmd batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How to use `[0-9]` in `if exist` statement. I want to check a file with second digit is 1-9 exist or not.

```
If exist "filepath\\a[1-9]*" (echo "yes")
```

It seems `[1-9]` wildcard does not work in `if exist` statement.

Do you have any idea how to implement this check?

e.g.
print "yes" when a file named a1 (a2da) exists, but not a0 (a0ss)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only check the second character, without considering the other characters after it, you can use something like this:

```
for /l %%n in (1,1,9) do if exist "a%%n*" set "ANS=%%n"
if defined ANS echo yes
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is a batch file, and is only written once, there's little need to try to make your command as short as possible. Therefore just use one `dir` command and one `echo` command, instead of the currently accepted answer which essentially runs ten `if` commands, potentially nine `set` commands, and one `echo` command.

```sh
@Dir "filepath\a1*" "filepath\a2*" "filepath\a3*" "filepath\a4*" "filepath\a5*" "filepath\a6*" "filepath\a7*" "filepath\a8*" "filepath\a9*" /B /A:-D 2>NUL 1>&2 && Echo Yes
```

As `filepath` is constant, you could even do it like this:

```sh
@CD /D "filepath" 2>NUL && (Dir a1* a2* a3* a4* a5* a6* a7* a8* a9* /B /A:-D 2>NUL 1>&2 && Echo Yes)
```

*Please note however, that your question is not clear enough to determine your full task. This example will print `Yes` if `a[123456789]…` exists in `filepath`, it will do that regardless of whether a file named `a0…` also exists in `filepath`.*

Comment: I edited my answer, and it does exactly what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to use PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows system it is already installed.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Test-Path -Path '.\a[1-9]*'"
```

Answer (score 0):

The one and only command in `cmd` that supports (a crippled version of) REGEX is `findstr`. So you can use that to complete your task:

```
dir /a-d "%filepath%\a*" | findstr /ib "a[123456789].*" >nul && echo yes || echo no
```

Note, this will also find files like `a12anything.txt` and `A2anything.txt` but not `a0anything.txt`.